# select ng-change in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have been looking for answer for this but cannot find any where.

I have table which has select and date input

```
<table id="tblCorrAction" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: #aeccea; color: #555; border: solid 1px #aeccea;">
            <th style="width:18%;">RArea</th>
            <th style="width:37%;">P</th>
            <th style="width:20%;">C</th>
            <th style="width:25%;">CAction</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="ca in CASelectList">
             <td>{{ca.QT}}</td>
             <td>{{ca.CAPT}}</td>
             <td>
                 <select name="caC_{{ca.QuesID}}" ng-model="item" class="form-control" 
                     ng-selected="ca.Corrected" ng-required="true" 
                     ng-change="GetCorrectedCAData(ca, item)" 
                     ng-options="corr as corr.caText for corr in correctedOption">
                     <option value="">--Select--</option>
                 </select>                                               
             </td>
             <td>
                 <span>
                     <input name="caDate_{{ca.QuesID}}" type="text" datepicker="" 
                     ng-model="ca.caDate"/>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

In my controller

$scope.correctedOption = [{ caValue: 1, caText: 'Yes' }, { caValue: 2, caText: 'No' }];
```

So now what I am trying to do is if use selects yes in select option then user can enter value in datetime input and if if user selects no the entered value should be reset. I tried few things, none of it worked

First :

```
$scope.GetCorrectedCAData = function (ca, item) {
    if (item.caValue === 2) {
        $scope.ca.caDate = ""
    }
}

this did not work. Error : Cannot set property 'caDate' of undefined
at ChildScope.$scope.GetCorrectedCAData
```

2nd : Added id to input

```
<input id="caDate_{{ca.QuesID}}" name="caDate_{{ca.QuesID}}" type="text" datepicker="" 
                     ng-model="ca.caDate"/>
And in controller
if (item.caValue === 2) {
        angular.element(document.querySelector("#caDate_" + ca.QuesID)).val("");
    }
this also did not work. Error:Missing instance data for this datepicker
```

3rd: looping through CASelectList a splice the row and add the spliced row with empty data for date. I do not want to use this as there can be many many many records.

Datepicker directive

```
ngControlMod.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
            $(el).datepicker({
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you post the points in the controller that are relevant to the question. What is `$scope.ca`?

Comment: CASelectList populates the table using ng-repeat. <tr ng-repeat="ca in CASelectList">.please look at the table above. so input and select can be bound by ca.caDate  and ca.Corrected. So when user chooses no for answer i wanted to use $scope.ca.caDate = "" to remove the selected date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ca` in the `ng-repeat` is not the same `ca` as in `$scope.ca` in the controller. When you are doing `$scope.ca` it means that the controller has a `$scope` variable called `ca` on it. Like this,

```
var Controller = function($scope) {
    $scope.ca = {
        caDate: "some date";
    }
}
```

You get that `Error : Cannot set property 'caDate' of undefined` because `$scope.ca` doesn't exist on the `$scope.`

If you want to reference the value inside each `CASelectList` in the `ng-repeat` (Which I think you want) then you just drop the `$scope.` in front of `ca`. So your code will look like this,

```
var Controller = function($scope) {
    $scope.GetCorrectedCAData = function (ca, item) {
        if (item.caValue === 2) {
            ca.caDate = ""; // This will change the ca value of the certain ca in CASelectList
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it did not work. caDate does not reset. I used this 
 if(SelectCorrected.caValue === 2) {
            $scope.ca = {
                caDate: ""
            }
        }

Comment: Don't change it to `$scope.ca = ...` Just drop `$scope.` before `ca.caDate = "";`

Comment: oh my bad. let me try again

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood that ca in the ng-repeat is not the same ca as in $scope.ca in the controller. So how without $scope there is a two way binding. Though I have just started using angular for the first time my understanding is  that if I have to update anything in view I needed $scope

Comment: In your example, you aren't two way binding. You are simply calling the method `GetCorrectedCAData` passing in the object `ca` created from the `ng-repeat`. You are simply changing the object passed in, which happens to be an object in the `CASelectList`.